# Preventing entering new records before all the fields filled, in MsExcel

Tags: excel, vba, record

I have a Worksheet in Excel:
[image]

My goal - user shouldn't be able to proceed before all the fields are filled from my drop down lists.

Otherwise - some sort of alert should appear or just doesn't let them proceed to the next record, before all the fields are entered with data.

One other important detail - my Form contains dropdown lists in all fields
That's why just a simple data validation rule won't work.
(There already other rules and formulas)

Is it still possible to do what described in vba, perhaps?
I have excel 2017

thank you!

**update from Hell--1931**
I probably do something wrong
I placed your code as following:

```
     Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
     Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long, 
                                  emptyCells As Range

      Set sh = Worksheets("ClientSatisfactionForm") ' very important to fully 
                                             qualify it (not ActiveSheet)!
      lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
      lastCol = sh.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
     On Error Resume Next
     Set emptyCells = sh.Range(sh.Cells(1, 1), sh.Cells(lastRow, 
                        lastCol)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
     If Err.Number = 1004 Then
     Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0: Exit Sub
     End If
   On Error GoTo 0
   If emptyCells.Cells.Count > 0 Then
      MsgBox "There are empty cells, which must be filled: " & 
                                        emptyCells.Address(0, 0)
     sh.Activate: emptyCells.Select
     Exit Sub
   End If
  End Sub
```

Now, it's not displays any error messages (as it did in previous version - when I executed in on close event), even if I enter empty row it now just asks about saving sheet....

PS - whenever I change event to "Before Close"  this code works as well as the previous one. But still lets exit out of Worksheet saving empty cells ..

Comment: Very doable, i would recommend you create a front end Userform in excel. The users will then need to enter all fields and click a 'submit' style button, before it populates a table in the back end of your spreadsheet.

Comment: @Bobby Heyer I saw a few examples of the User Entry Forms online. 
The problem with it is that users can't edit it or go betw. the records.
Theoretically of course it's possible, but requires a bit more advance knowledge of vba and excel

Comment: Is your "Data Entry Form" a form or a worksheet? If a sheet, like it looks, independent of the Dropdown lists or not, do you need checking if all fields are not empty? If yes, you don not show us the column headers and It would be necessary to know which is the columns range to be checked. Then, are there inputs being result of formulas? Even if the formula returns ""...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

**After editing**: Now `sh` **cannot be `ActiveSheet`**, anymore! It must be clearly qualified. Meaning **to use the involved worksheet name**.

```
Sub checkEmptyCells()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long, emptyCells As Range
  
  Set sh = Worksheets("Involved sheet name") ' very important to fully qualify it (not ActiveSheet)!
  lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
  lastCol = sh.cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
  On Error Resume Next
   Set emptyCells = sh.Range(sh.cells(1, 1), sh.cells(lastRow, lastCol)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
   If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0: Exit Sub
   End If
   On Error GoTo 0
  If emptyCells.cells.count > 0 Then
    MsgBox "There are empty cells, which must be filled: " & emptyCells.Address(0, 0)
    sh.Activate: emptyCells.Select
    Exit Sub
  End If
End Sub
```

The above code assumes that there are not cells having formulas which returns "". In such a case `xlCellTypeBlanks` does not consider them like being empty...

**Edited**:

In order to not allow leaving from the sheet in discussion, until all cells are filled, the above `Sub` (however it will be named) should be simple called in the `Worksheet_Deactivate` event, as following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
   checkEmptyCells
End Sub
```

Comment: @Hell-1931: Did you test my suggested code? A little feedback would not kill anybody, I think...

Comment: Sorry for the long delay  I tested your code. Works great!  But one other thing - I added 2 lines - to On Error GoTo NoBlanks - before the code  And - NoBlanks:
    Resume Next - after the code. I execute your code (Sub) as function Before_Close event.  I am wondering if I can add something so that the Worksheet unable to be closed until all the empty records filled

Comment: @Hell-1931: Glad I could help! 1. Why did you feel the need to use an error handler in  such a short code? I think it is better to raise an error when something unexpected/bad happens, then over-passing it. But if this is your choice, it does not bother the code itself. 2. A `BeforeClose` event exists only in `ThisWorkbook` module and it refers to the workbook close. A solution to your problem,  like I could understand it, would be to use `Worksheet_Deactivate` event. Keep the above code in a `Sub` like it is and call it from the event. I will adapt the above code with a little piece of code.

Comment: I used error handler because otherwise it showed "RuntimeError No cells were found" message - if there all cells filled (and no empty left). Simply - to avoid this problem.   I tried using Worksheet_Deactivate  but still the same - lets me exit out of Worksheet even if some empty cells ((...  I guess there needed some vba update

Comment: @Hell-1931: This error should be handled in a different way. I will adapt the code from this point of view, too. For this specific error number. I must confess,  I did not check the code for the case of no empty cells... :)

Comment: I must be done something incorrect. If you'd please check my last updates (where you posted you updated code, I added my explanation)

Comment: @Hell-1931: What do you mean by **my last updates (where you posted you updated code**? Did you try editing my answer? If yes, this is not a logic way and you cannot do it without my accept. I never accept editing of my answer, because in case of a mistake I cannot know where from it appears. But you can edit your question, **post the code you use** and comment whatever you consider being necessary...

Comment: Sorry, I updated my original post for your review...

Comment: Did you keep "Involved sheet name", as you show us in the updated question? I would like to see the code **as you use it**! Did you use instead of it **your sheet name to be processed**?

Comment: No, I used my own sheet name  -  "ClientSatisfactionForm" 
("Involved sheet name" came up in my edits accidently)

Comment: @Hell-1931:  Is the event triggered? Try putting a break on first line `Set sh = Worksheets("ClientSatisfactionForm")` and see if it stops on it. If yes, try running the code line by line, pressing F8 and see what is happening?

Comment: @Hell-1931: Still alive? Does your code show the `MsgBox` with the cells address to be filled? Do you have TeamViewer installed?

Comment: @FaneGuru i cant use TeamViewer as it's 1 30 am at my place, sorry
After setting break, I tried to press Debug / Run To Cursor (Ctrl+F8) - error shows after the 2nd run - Subscript Out of Range

Comment: @Hell-1931: In these circumstances you better go to bed. Tomorrow is another day, too... In my country it is 11:45 AM. You will tell me (your tomorrow) on which line the error appears... Besides all that, if you have TeamViewer installed, it dos not produce any noise... :) Now i will only say Good night!

Comment: @FanaDuru  thx, have a great day!  About the TeamViewer yes it won't produce any noise, but the talking will - for sure...

Comment: @Hell-1931: No any need to talk. We will open an Notepad and write whatever we would need to communicate. But (tomorrow), if you would be available to connect on TeamViewer, it would be enough to have the workbook in discussion open and VBE on the code we are talking about. In 5 to 10 minutes I think I will show you where the problem is... But now, Final Good night!